# Find webpage element with changing location, but non-changing text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate an element on a couple of webpages. The webpages are all on the same website, but the structure of the website changes sometimes per page.

When I inspect the pages I see the following full `xpaths`:

```
1; /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/article/div/div/p[3]/strong/a[1]
2, /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/article/div/div/p[10]/a[1]
3; /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/article/div/div/p[3]/strong/a
4; /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/article/div/div/p[3]/strong/a
5; /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/article/div/div/p[3]/strong/a
6; /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/article/div/div/p[10]/a[1]
7; /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/article/div/div/p[10]/a[1]
```

with [1](https://fullmatchsports.co/augsburg-vs-bayern-munich-full-match-bundesliga-2018/), [2](https://fullmatchsports.co/augsburg-vs-borussia-dortmund-full-match-bundesliga-2017-18/), [3](https://fullmatchsports.co/augsburg-vs-eintracht-frankfurt-full-match-bundesliga-2018/), [4](https://fullmatchsports.co/augsburg-vs-freiburg-full-match-bundesliga-2017/), [5](https://fullmatchsports.co/augsburg-vs-hamburger-full-match-bundesliga-2018/), [6](https://fullmatchsports.co/augsburg-vs-hannover-full-match-bundesliga-2017/), [7](https://fullmatchsports.co/augsburg-vs-hertha-berlin-full-match-bundesliga-2017/)

The text of the final element always contains the string `Uptobox`
How do I locate the element each time, even when the structure is different.

Current code (works only for a couple of the above mentioned and has different criterium):

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[contains(., "Download")]//a')  # Need to adjust this to final uptobox-level
```

Please let me know what I need to adjust

Kind regards,

Huib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `//a[.='Uptobox']` to get **Uptobox** button, but you need to wait until element will be in the HTML. If you'll click use `element_to_be_clickable` condition to wait for element to be clickable.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)

uptobox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[.='Uptobox']")))
uptobox.click()
```

Update, `a.btn[rel*='nofollow']` css selector will work on all pages:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)

links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn[rel*='nofollow']")))
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```